# Problem with running a php project in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I am very new in Wamp server and I try to open a project in it. I successfully installed the Wamp server, but it returns me this error.

```
There is an error.
It seems that a PHP installation is declared in the environment variable PATH
C:\PHP

Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment variable.
Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version
is detrimental to the proper functioning of Wampserver.
```

I tried to check the local variables in my computer but I didn't find the C:\PHP in order to delete it. Can you please suggest me what to do?

Comment: You are on a PC right?

Comment: I think you need to supress it in your enviroment variable in your controle panel

Comment: @Stender yes :)

Comment: like `http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,150782,printview,page=1`

Comment: Let's give it a try!

Comment: Praveen also suggested me something similar!I checked the Php version that I use with php-v and this returned me the 7.1.12. When I go to the local variables, I can't find this one, but I can find these versions: 5.6.38, 7.0.32, 7.1.22, 7.2.10!!